# Not able to connect spring boot application with SQL SERVER Database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, connection

I am trying to connect my spring boot application with sql server database but it throwing an Exception and saying :

```
020-08-18 16:58:11.580 ERROR 14800 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. .
```

*However I am able to connect with oracle database the issue arises when I try to connect with sql server*.

**here is the application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.*.*\\DB2008;databaseName=mydbname
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

here is the detailed error:

```
2020-08-18 16:58:11.580 ERROR 14800 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:37aa16bd-92f0-4af0-a090-06f2349cb51a".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1881) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2484) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following the below steps:

Edit C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\security\java.security

find the below variable it will have multiple comma separated values remove one value which I have mentioned below:

**Find:  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=**

**Remove:   3DES_EDE_CBC**

This should fix it!

Comment: Here is the official documentation :
https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html

Answer (score -1):

In this case can you can try the following steps.

1. Make sure that your SQL server is running locally(Are you trying to connect to a remove SQL server?)
2. Alternatively, In your URL after your Data base name use this statement `jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/someDatabase?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: The database is located on different machine but it's within the organization.

Comment: yes I tried it's throwing same exception :( 

The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response.

Comment: What version and vendor of JDK you're using like oracle JDK or Open JDK ? Because it seems your JDK supports the TLS 1.2 but still by default it uses the TLS 1.0 and for that reason we see that client application initiates TLS 3-way handshake with a TLS 1.0 client hello and connections are failing.  To fix that we will need to override some property based on JDK you're using! Please see [this article for your reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/jdbc-connections-fails-with-quot-the-driver-could-not-establish/ba-p/414157)

Comment: I am using oracle jdk 1.8 . Yes I also searched alot and found the same issue . So I think the problem you identified is correct. I also gone through the article you shared  but i don't find the directories mentioned in the article for resolving the issue. Because I am not using the IBMJava so there no directory related to it. Can you please help me resolving it .. Thanks in Advance. and thanks for replying.

Comment: @KaranSachrani, Use [this article, it should help you to fix the issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220076/discussion-between-amit-mishra-and-karan-sachrani).